# RecyclerView not showing anything in fragment

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am trying to display a list of items from by DB using recyclerView. However, the recyclerView does not show anything even though the code runs well without any error. What could be the probable reason? If anyone could assist me please.

My code is as follows:

RequestsAdapter.java

```
package com.bloodconnect.Fragments;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.bloodconnect.Model.Request;
import com.bloodconnect.R;

import java.util.List;

public class RequestsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RequestsAdapter.RequestsViewHolder>{

    private Context mCtx;
    private List<Request> requestList;

    public RequestsAdapter(Context mCtx, List<Request> requestList) {
        this.mCtx = mCtx;
        this.requestList = requestList;

    }

    @Override
    public RequestsViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mCtx);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.show_request_template, null);
        return new RequestsViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RequestsViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Request requests = requestList.get(position);

        holder.request_name.setText(requests.getName());
        holder.request_blood_group.setText(requests.getBlood_group());
        holder.request_date.setText(String.valueOf(requests.getDate_of_request()));
        holder.request_address.setText(String.valueOf(requests.getAddress()));
        holder.request_lat_lng.setText(String.valueOf(requests.getLat_lng()));
    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return requestList.size();
    }

    class RequestsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView request_name, request_address, request_date, request_lat_lng, request_blood_group;

        public RequestsViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            request_name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.show_request_name);
            request_blood_group = itemView.findViewById(R.id.show_request_bloodgroup);
            request_date = itemView.findViewById(R.id.show_request_date);
            request_address = itemView.findViewById(R.id.show_request_address);
            request_lat_lng = itemView.findViewById(R.id.show_request_location);
        }
    }

}
```

ShowRequestsFragment.java

```
package com.bloodconnect.Fragments;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;
import com.bloodconnect.R;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class ShowRequestsFragment extends Fragment {

    private static final String URL_REQUESTS = "http://142.93.216.24/android/api.php?apicall=get_requests";
    List<com.bloodconnect.Model.Request> requestsList;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;

    public ShowRequestsFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View rootView =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_show_requests, container, false);
        recyclerView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.listRecyclerView);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));

        //initializing the requestList
        requestsList = new ArrayList<>();

        loadRequests();

        //creating adapter object and setting it to recyclerview
        RequestsAdapter adapter;
        adapter = new RequestsAdapter(getActivity(), requestsList);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        return rootView;
    }

    private void loadRequests() {

        /*
         * Creating a String Request
         * The request type is GET defined by first parameter
         * The URL is defined in the second parameter
         * Then we have a Response Listener and a Error Listener
         * In response listener we will get the JSON response as a String
         * */
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(com.android.volley.Request.Method.GET, URL_REQUESTS,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        try {
                            //converting the string to json array object
                            JSONArray array = new JSONArray();

                            //traversing through all the object
                            for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {

                                //getting product object from json array
                                JSONObject request = array.getJSONObject(i);

                                //adding the product to product list
                                requestsList.add(new com.bloodconnect.Model.Request(
                                        request.getString("name"),
                                        request.getString("blood_group"),
                                        request.getString("date_of_request"),
                                        request.getString("lat_lng"),
                                        request.getString("address")
                                ));
                            }

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                    }
                });

        //adding our stringrequest to queue
        Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext()).add(stringRequest);
    }




}
```

I am populating the list in a fragment that extends a navigationDrawerActivity.

Comment: Check if `requestsList` is returning the data or not? add this and set a break point `Log.d("tag" + requestsList.toString);`

Comment: Any hints on how I can do that @ʍѳђઽ૯ท. Let me try

Comment: When I put the adapter immediately after the list, it gives me a RecyclerView, No Apater Found error @ʍѳђઽ૯ท

Comment: Check my answer. I’m suspecting about the codes which is adding data to the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the `Adapter` just right after the values receives in `onResponse` method and get a test data as follows:

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
 JSONObject request = array.getJSONObject(i);

 String name = request.getString("name");

    requestsList.add(name)
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

This is just an example. I'm suspecting that:

```
requestsList.add(new com.bloodconnect.Model.Request(
               request.getString("name"),
               request.getString("blood_group"),
               request.getString("date_of_request"),
               request.getString("lat_lng"),
               request.getString("address")
       ));
```

Might not set the data to the `requestsList`.

---

However, ***using `GSON` and converting the current json output*** is the best choice nowadays.

Comment: Thanks. I got my problem :)